# Is int i{}; equivalent to int i=0;?

Tags: c++

If I understood correctly, the first one will value-initialize i which has the effect of zero initializing it, so are these statements guaranteed to be equivalent by the standard ?

Comment: What other behaviour do you expect from either of these lines?

Comment: only that i==0.